# How to specific not converging criterion of an iteration in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi everyone this is What I did to carry out an iteration method(gauss seidel) and I want when iteration number greater than 30 it will stop and generate the corresponding result up to 30 iteration. But I wonder why the output `result` were so weird and I try to check the value on the command window by typing `x_ans(:,1)` it gives me the correct value. It really made me frustrated why the generate result were not the same. Or any other circumstance or function can be used to set for not converging condition. Sincerely thanks in advance for every single help.

```
clear;clc
A = [2 8 3 1;0 2 -1 4;7 -2 1 2;-1 0 5 2]
B = [-2;4;3;5]
Es = 1e-5


n = length(B);
x = zeros(n,1);
Ea = ones(n,1);
iter = 0;

while max(Ea) >= Es
    if iter <= 30
        iter = iter + 1;
        x_old = x;
        for i = 1:n
           j = 1:n;
           j(i) = [];
            x_cal = x;
            x_cal(i) = [];
            x(i) = (B(i) - sum(A(i,j) * x_cal)) / A(i,i);
        end
    else
        break
    end

    x_ans(:,iter) = x;
    Ea(:,iter) =abs(( x - x_old) ./ x);

    end

result = [1:iter; x_ans; Ea]'
```

Comment: Th code cannot be reproduced since not all variables are defined. General rule is to do `clear all` to clear all variables and try to run your code. Post it if there is no error with undefined variables.

Comment: @yuk I have edited my code..help you could help me figure out what is the problem..thanks a lot.....

Comment: Did you notice that the displayed result variable output values have been divided by 1.0e+043?  If you look at each iteration the results should match x_ans. For example, look at result(1,:)

Comment: @grantnz ya i thk i knew it alrdy..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the formulas and they are all OK. On a side note, the sum is not necessary. The problem lies with your input data - try reordering! check for example the following, which works

```
A = [7 -2 1 2;
     2 8 3 1;
     -1 0 5 2;
     0 2 -1 4;]
B = [3;-2;5;4]
```

see the [wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) under convergence.